# Ошибка в коде на фреймворке kivy

Tags: python, python-3.6, kivy

Пытаюсь сделать рулетку для проекта, но в ходе написания кода появилась ошибка

Я хочу, чтобы при окончании анимации создавался новый виджет который будет повторять анимацию 2-ого и так несколько раз(наподобие рулетки)
Я пробовал разными методами(через `on_complete`, `duration` и т.д.), но больше пригляделся `have_properties_to_animate`
Подскажите как исправить ошибку или моя логика не верная
Сама ошибка:

```
"have_properties_to_animate() missing 1 required positional argument: 'widget'"
```

Это часть задуманного кода (скелет)
Просто я не пойму, почему компилятор пишет ошибку - 'Нет виджета, хотя я его вложил'
Код
[image: КОД]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

поменяйте строку

```
Animation.have_properties_to_animate(widget)
```

на

```
Animation().have_properties_to_animate(widget)
```

Comment: Cпасибо, это помогло