# Oшибка - NoneType' object has no attribute

Tags: python, kivy

Я хочу сделать подобие рулетки (виджет исчезает, и появляется новый виджет).Код делится на, отвечающий за исчезание виджета, т.е. удаляется начальный виджет, за создание нового виджета, и за анимирование начального виджета(сначала анимируется начальный виджет, потом он удаляется, потом создаётся новый виджет, и в конце анимируется новый виджет) удаляется виджет после окончания анимации начального виджета с помощью метода have_properties_to_animate().Ошибка:

> ```
> 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'support'" в строке "if self.support == True:
> ```

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.event import  EventDispatcher
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.animation import Animation
from kivy.config import Config 
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', 0)
Config.set('graphics', 'width', 500)
Config.set('graphics', 'height', 500)
class RuletkaApp(App):
    def build(self):
        widget = BoxLayout(orientation = 'horizontal',padding = [100,150,100,150])
        widget.add_widget(Button(text = 'DragonLor',size =(80, 80)))
        anim = Animation(x = 200,y = 0, size=(0, 0), duration = 3, t='in_quad')
        anim.start(widget)
        self.support = Animation().have_properties_to_animate(widget)
        def position(self):
            if self.support == True:
                widget.add_widget(Button(text = 'Dragon',size = (80,80)))
                anim2 = Animation(x = 0, y = 0, size = (20, 20), duration = 2, t = 'in_quad')
            return anim2 

        newanimation = position(self.support)
        newanimation.start(widget)

        return widget
if __name__ == '__main__':
    RuletkaApp().run()
```

Comment: Что нужно сделать? Нужно взять учебник и освежить знания об областях видимости и действия переменных. Заодно о том, как работают функции. Ваша ``anim2`` нигде (!) не определяется, даже там, где вам кажется, что она определяется (кстати, где это?)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1188886/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B5-kivy